# How to create a regex for this format B001169875?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regex to match this format: B001169875

Can someone help me?

Trying to make it work using jQuery Validate custom method:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("brandnumber", function(value, element) {
       return  /B\d{9}/m.test(value);
  }, "Account number must start with B and be followed by 9 numbers.");
```

Comment: `/^B001169875$/` will match that…

Comment: Does it always start with a `B`?

Comment: Yes, always starts with a B and then always followed by numbers.

Comment: @jrutter Consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it always starts with a `B` and is followed by 9 numbers then this will do it:

```
^B\d{9}$
```

And you could use it like this (depending on how you want to use it):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("brandnumber", 
    function(value, element) { 
        return /^B\d{9}$/m.test(value); 
    }, 
    "Account number must start with B and be followed by 9 numbers."
);
```

Comment: This works great - I created a custom validator method to test against this using your regex.   jQuery.validator.addMethod("brandnumber", function(value, element) {
       return  /B\d{9}/m.test(value);
  }, "Account number must start with B and be followed by 9 numbers.");

Comment: @jrutter - Did you test it with the following string: [AAB001169875AA](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=B%5Cd%2B&input=AAB001169875AA)?

Comment: No, good call - that breaks it. Also, if I add more than 9 numbers it doesnt prevent it.

Comment: i've updated my answer with your new requirement. glad it helped

Comment: +1. And @jrutter, you didn't really give the correct specifications at the beginning. But what you want is clear now :)

Answer (score 5):

You should specify more details about the format. But it will be something along the lines of:

```
[A-Z][0-9]{9}
```

It means: one capital letter (A..Z), then nine digits (0..9).

Answer (score 5):

You said the string will always start by `B` followed by numbers. The regex depends on how many numbers you want to match:

- exactly 9 numbers : [`/B\d{9}/`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=B%5Cd%2b&input=B001169875)
- zero or more numbers: [`/B\d*/`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=B%5Cd%2a&input=B001169875)
- one or more numbers: [`/B\d+/`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=B%5Cd%2b&input=B001169875)

Also, you probably have to use `^` and `$` to specify that the string should only contain B and the numbers: `/^B\d{9}$/`, `/^B\d*$/` or `/^B\d+$/`.

Comment: Use `\z` in preference to `$`. `$` means end-of-string (possibly preceded by newline).